# XSLT to replace a child node element value with another child node element value

Tags: xslt

How to move a child node element value to another child node value using xslt. I need to replace the dummy city with the actual city value from a different child node.

In the below example i need to move the city from Address child node to the Name child node.

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<M:Top_Node xmlns:M="urn:com">
<M:First_Node>
    <M:Employee>
        <M:Name>
            <M:Employee_ID>001</M:Employee_ID>
            <M:Name>sam</M:Name>
            <M:City>Dummy_City_CA</M:City>
        </M:Name>
        <M:Address>
            <M:City>Actual_City_CA</M:City>
            <M:State>CA</M:State>
        </M:Address>
    </M:Employee>
    <M:Employee>
        <M:Name>
            <M:Employee_ID>002</M:Employee_ID>
            <M:Name>Van</M:Name>
            <M:City>Dummy_City_NY</M:City>
        </M:Name>
        <M:Address>
            <M:City>Actual_City_NY</M:City>
            <M:State>NY</M:State>
        </M:Address>
    </M:Employee>
</M:First_Node>
```

***Expected Output:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<M:Top_Node xmlns:M="urn:com">
<M:First_Node>
    <M:Employee>
        <M:Name>
            <M:Employee_ID>001</M:Employee_ID>
            <M:Name>sam</M:Name>
            <M:City>Actual_City_CA</M:City>
        </M:Name>
        <M:Address>
            **<M:City>Actual_City_CA</M:City>**
            <M:State>CA</M:State>
        </M:Address>
    </M:Employee>
    <M:Employee>
        <M:Name>
            <M:Employee_ID>002</M:Employee_ID>
            <M:Name>Van</M:Name>
            **<M:City>Actual_City_NY</M:City>**
        </M:Name>
        <M:Address>
            <M:City>Actual_City_NY</M:City>
            <M:State>NY</M:State>
        </M:Address>
    </M:Employee>
</M:First_Node>
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a template for that element

```
<xsl:template match="M:Employee/M:Name/M:City">
  <xsl:copy-of select="../../M:Address/M:City"/>
</xsl:template>
```

plus the identity transformation template of course.